# How can I cycle a class on 3 elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, jcarousellite

I'm using [jCarouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) to cycle between 3 elements. I've setup the plugin to do this fine, including 3x `.bulletX` which slides to each element, i.e. bullet 1 slides to element 1, etc.

However what I want is to cycle the class `.active` on the `.bulletX` to designate which element is being shown, similar to nivoslider.

```
<div class="bullet1">If this is clicked, is leads to element1</div>
<div class="bullet2">If this is clicked, is leads to element2</div>
<div class="bullet3">If this is clicked, is leads to element3</div>
```

I feel like there is something I can do with `.addClass` and `.removeClass`, but can't quite get the semantics of a loop in my head.

`.active` applied to `.bullet2` manually

[image]

Edit Full HTML

```
<div class="twwetHolder">
    <div class="tweet">
     <ul>
        <li>
            <div>element 1</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>element 2</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>element 3</div>
        </li>
     </ul>

    </div>  
<div class="bullet1"></div>
<div class="bullet2"></div>
<div class="bullet3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

I'd suggest you add a class to each bullet (another) and then use the btnGo event and a click event to add the class.

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/fg6d4/1/

```
<div class="bullet1 btngo">a</div>
<div class="bullet2 btngo">b</div>
<div class="bullet3 btngo">c</div>

$('.tweet').jCarouselLite({btnGo:$('.btngo')});

    $('.btngo').click(function() {
       $('.btngo').removeClass('active'); 
       $(this).addClass('active');

    });
​
```

Original:

You could try these options:

```
 beforeStart: function(a) {
      $(a).removeClass('active');
    },
   afterEnd: function(a) {
        $(a).addClass('active');
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work with this function, as I have 'bullet1', 'bullet2', 'bullet3'. That is that needs to be .removeClass and .addClass on.

Comment: Can you mock up a jsfiddle with the code. I'm not quite understanding the question especially when you say "cycle the class .active"

Comment: It's pretty much the External Controls demo at http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/#demo but using a div with a background image instead of a <button> element :)

Comment: I get that but where are you trying to add the active class?  To the slides or something inside the slides?

Comment: I've added the full HTML where you can see each bullet leading to each respective element

Comment: Thanks that helped me understand a little better.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: Perfect my friend, you are really talented.

Answer (score 0):

`.toggleClass()` might help you - http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/